# tia bbg python - Overriding "#N/A Field Not Applicable"

Tags: python, bloomberg

I'm trying to request fields using get_attributes, but it returns a FieldError for anything not applicable (e.g. requesting ex-dividend date on a non-dividend paying stock).

```
FieldError: (BRK/B US Equity, DVD_EX_DT, BAD_FLD, Field not applicable to security)
```

Is there already an override for this situation or do i have to iterate over each ticker then combine?

```
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()
sids_index = mgr[TICKERS]
bloomberg_fields =  ['BEST_DIV_YLD',  # Forward Dividend Yield
                     'DVD_EX_DT',  # Ex-Dividend Date
                     'EXPECTED_REPORT_DT',  # Next Earnings Call Date
                     'GROSS_MARGIN',  # Gross Margin
                     'OPER_MARGIN',  # Operating Margin
                     'PROF_MARGIN']  # Profit Margin
df_data = sids_index.get_attributes(bloomberg_fields, OVERRIDE)
```

Comment: Yes it's expected to receive an error message if a field is not defined for a given security, but the underlying API will send data for all the fields which have a value.
I'm not familiar with the python API but I imagine there is a way to access the valid data that you have received.

Comment: I'm thinking I can loop through the list of tickers and pass on any requests that return the error then combine all valid requests. I just want to make sure I'm not missing an override somewhere before doing so.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the errors with an override. But when you get the error, you don't have a way to access the values returned for the fields that "worked"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out [`xbbg`](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io) package with following lines:

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdp(
    tickers=[
        'BRK/B US Equity', 'C US Equity'
    ],
    flds=[
        'Best_Div_Yld', 'DVD_Ex_Dt', 'Expected_Report_Dt',
        'Gross_Margin', 'Oper_Margin', 'Prof_Margin',
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
             ticker               field       value
0   BRK/B US Equity        Best_Div_Yld         -  
1   BRK/B US Equity           DVD_Ex_Dt         NaN
2   BRK/B US Equity  Expected_Report_Dt  2019-02-25
3   BRK/B US Equity        Gross_Margin       18.37
4   BRK/B US Equity         Oper_Margin       10.86
5   BRK/B US Equity         Prof_Margin       18.56
6       C US Equity        Best_Div_Yld        2.96
7       C US Equity           DVD_Ex_Dt  2018-11-02
8       C US Equity  Expected_Report_Dt  2019-01-14
9       C US Equity        Gross_Margin         NaN
10      C US Equity         Oper_Margin       31.86
11      C US Equity         Prof_Margin       -7.73
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following override:

```
LocalTerminal.get_reference_data(tk, flds, ignore_field_error=1, ignore_security_error=1)
```

output is then generated as nan or nat